# Getting process remotely

Tags: c#

I am running VirtualBox and would like to retrieve a certain process that's running on the host. 
Both are running 64 bit versions of Windows 7. I have administrator access, enabled Remote Sharing, added both PCs
to a homegroup, and disabled my firewall but I am still getting an exception of `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Couldn't connect to remote machine.'`

I've tried both `GetProcesses` and `GetProcessesByName`, both are throwing the same exception.

```
public void StartMainThread()
{
    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(Environment.ProcessorCount, Environment.ProcessorCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < Program.data.Threads; i++)
    {
        mChildThreads[i] = new PixelThread();
    }
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate (object o) {
        this.mRunning = true;
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad", "ipaddress").Length == 0) // exception is thrown here
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to find window", "Error!");
            this.StopThread();
        }
        else
        {
            IntPtr mainWindowHandle = Process.GetProcesses("notepad", "ipaddress")[0].MainWindowHandle;
            if (mainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to find window", "Error!");
                this.StopThread();
            }
            else
            {
                ((MainForm)Form.ActiveForm).ProcessStatus("STATUS : Attached", Color.Green);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you name your virtualbox machine `ipaddress`? If not, why did you use `"ipaddress"` as the name of the machine?

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter of GetProcessByName should be an IP address. That is, either you set the variable and pass it (**without quoutes**) or you write it directly.

```
string ipaddress = "192.168.1.10";
```

and then:

```
Process.GetProcessByName("notepad", ipaddress);
```